# Reverse Geocoding using Blackberry 5.0 API example anyone?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

So the blackberry documentation shows you the following code example:

```
import net.rim.device.api.lbs.*;
import javax.microedition.location.*;

public class myReverseGeocode
{
    private Thread reverseGeocode;

    public myReverseGeocode()
    {
        reverseGeocode = new Thread(thread);
        reverseGeocode.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        reverseGeocode.start();
    }

    Runnable thread = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            AddressInfo addrInfo = null;

            int latitude  = (int)(45.423488 * 100000);
            int longitude = (int)(-80.32480 * 100000);

            try
            {
                Landmark[] results = Locator.reverseGeocode
                 (latitude, longitude, Locator.ADDRESS );

                if ( results != null && results.length > 0 )
                    addrInfo = results[0].getAddressInfo();
            }
            catch ( LocatorException lex )
            {
            }
        }
    };
}
```

How do I use the above mentioned code to pass in dynamic longitude/latitude values in my main application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this just a basic java question?  You have to use the 'final' keyword, so that the values can be passed in to the anonymous class held by the local variable 'thread'

```
public myReverseGeocode(final double latArg, final double lonArg)
{
    Runnable thread = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            AddressInfo addrInfo = null;

            int latitude  = (int)(latArg * 100000);
            int longitude = (int)(lonArg * 100000);

            try
            {
                Landmark[] results = Locator.reverseGeocode
                 (latitude, longitude, Locator.ADDRESS );

                if ( results != null && results.length > 0 )
                    addrInfo = results[0].getAddressInfo();
            }
            catch ( LocatorException lex )
            {
            }
        }
    };
    reverseGeocode = new Thread(thread);
    reverseGeocode.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    reverseGeocode.start();

 }
```

Comment: The latArg and lonArg still cannot be resolved in run(). That is they are not passed/accessible in the run method of runnable.

Comment: When I highlight over latArg it says: "latArg cannot be resolved". It is also underlined in red. The IDE I am using is eclipse with blackberry JDE 5.0 plugin.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the scope of the myReverseGeocode function.  I just edited my answer to fix the problem.

Comment: Michael, thanks so much. I truly appreciate it and sorry if I lack clarity on certain questions.